# Cordova cannot make back button work after addEventListener

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I cannot make back button on android work after addEventListener. How to make it work?

index.html file content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad();">
        <div><a href="page2.html">Go to page2</a></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            function onLoad() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            function onDeviceReady() {
                alert('device ready.');
                // Register the event listener
                document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
            }

            function onBackKeyDown() {
                // do nothing
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html file content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>Page2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><a href="index.html">Go to Index page</a></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cordova version is 3.5.0-0.2.7

What i want to do is...
**1.** Open the app > get alert 'device ready' > tap on back > exit the app.
Another step
**2.** Open the app > get alert 'device ready' > tap on 'Go to page2' > page2 open > tap on back > go back to index page > tap on back again > exit the app.

What i got...
**1.** Open the app > get alert 'device ready' > tap on back > **nothing happens. not exit.**
**2.** Open the app > get alert 'device ready' > tap on 'Go to page2' > page2 open > tap on back > **nothing happens. not go back.**

Comment: In your code `function onBackKeyDown` is empty. so it will not do anything because you are overriding the default behaviour with your function. If you remove or comment `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);` the statement then the default behaviour is to exit the app on pressing the back button.

Comment: In my real code it is not empty. It has track function that just track when user tap on back button.
In page2 it has no override backbutton. It should be able to go back but it is not.

Comment: Your `page2.html` is a separate html page with a head and body tag. So when  you load your **page2.html** the previous page JS scripts are no longer available. The page1 will be overwritten by page2 contents. so in your page2.html you have to again explicitly write the `backbutton` functionality in the same way that you did for `index.html`.

Comment: @frank Thank you for your help. 
Yes, page2 is a separate and it has no ``backbutton`` listener. so it should be able to go back to index.html page right? But it is not.
As i describe the step in "What i got..." in the question. Step 1 OK i understand that backbutton has override and i have to manually write window.history js code. 
But step 2. i should be able to go back to index.html page because it is normal page, no js, nothing override. 
I don't want ``backbutton`` listener from index.html to work in page2.html.

Comment: If i comment ``document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);`` as you said. It works as i espect in "What i want to do is.."
But if i did not comment that, the page2.html cannot go back to index.html page.

Comment: My mistake I should have used the word `similar` instead of `same`. What I meant that you should have a `similar` code in your page2. There should be a statement `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);` in **page2** as well, but the logic inside `onBackKeyDown` function should be to open the `index.html` page. To summarize, **Page2** backbutton function should contain functionality to go to page1 (index.html). Hope I have clarified my comments.